# show a usercontrol in wpf window by button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

I have user control and wanna show it by clicking a button in a window designed by wpf.
I made a control user project and referenced it in a wpf project in this way:

```
xmlns:myproj="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfControlLibrary1"
```

and in `<Grid>`tag I have this :

```
<myproj:UserControl1   Visibility="Hidden"
                       x:Name="customproj" />
```

and as I told I have a button in the main window in wpf project:

```
<Button Content="click me" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Height="31" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

but I don't know how to write the event of the `Button_Click`to open the control user.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //I don't know what to write!!!
        }
```

I searched a lot but didn't find a suitable answer for my problem!

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the **`Visibility`** of UserControl to **`Visible`**:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   customproj.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: this was my problem that i didn't notice that i should use the name of the user controler where i define in the definition tag in grid tag

Comment: This is not resource friendly. Assuming you have an application with lots of user controls loaded at runtime it could be quite heavy on compute resources. A way in which to instantiate these user controls using switch cases in code-behind may be preferred